# Изменить радиус круга

Tags: c++, наследование

У меня есть иерархия классов геометрических фигур:

```
struct Figure { 
  virtual void draw_figure() = 0;
}

struct Circle : Figure {
  Circle(int radius);
  void draw_figure();
  void set_radius(int radius);
}
```

В коде для отрисовки все фигуры представлены вектором `Figure*`, чтобы вызывать `draw_figure()` динамически. Но что если я хочу после создания круга изменить его радиус?

```
Figure* circle = new Circle(42);
circle -> set_radius(21);
```

Так это не получается сделать. Подскажите, как правильно действовать в такой ситуации. Добавлять `set_radius` в `Figure` нелогично, т.к. не всякой фигуре нужен этот метод, а делать `dynamic_cast` скорее хак, чем нормальное решение.

Comment: Ну, в данном случае это не хак, а скорее изъян проекта. Для **отрисовки** не нужно менять радиус. Так что лезть в этот вектор, чтоб изменить радиус - это значит менять его смысл... Так что или нужно менять сам дизайн, или использовать веревочку для подвязывания отпадающей детали - `dynamic_cast`. Все лучше, чем безусловное приведение в стиле С...

Comment: @Harry как лучше изменить дизайн? фигуры уникальные, хранятся только в векторе

Comment: Дак откуда же я знаю? Это всю задачу нужно разбирать и смотреть, что к чему, и зачем посреди рисования менять размеры фигур...

Comment: Используйте [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) в таких ситуациях.

Answer (score 1):

Подойдем к задаче с другой стороны. Наверно, вряд ли Вы хотите просто поменять радиус у одной произвольной фигуры (не круга, а фигуры). И более того, если уж так случилось, то код, который меняет радиус, знает, что это круг. Либо, код, который меняет радиус, на самом деле меняет размер фигуры.

А теперь уже и решение появляется. Можно в класс фигуры добавить виртуальную функцию "изменить размер". Для круга она  будет менять радиус, для квадрата сторону. И так далее (для прямоугольника может менять диагональ, а стороны - пропорционально).

И есть второй случай. Добавлять новую функцию в класс (менять интерфейс базового класса) не хочется. В этом случае поможет [паттерн визитор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)) и на [хабре есть статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/133183/).
Этот паттерн поможет решить такую задачу "увеличить размеры всех моих фигур".